# Shows Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode

Tags: android, gradle, admob, build.gradle, barcode-scanner

Everything was working fine until I added    `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'` this dependency for showing ads in-app.

I am getting below error message while building the application. error gets removed if I remove ad library.

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck
```

App level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.creatorisone.chargingtheftsecurityalarm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.04"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), "proguard-rules.pro"
         }
    }
     configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:17.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
    implementation 'xyz.belvi.mobilevision:barcodescanner:2.0.3'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.3'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'

}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I have tried multiple solutions provided on StackOverflow but nothing is working in my case

1. ["Error: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51743786/error-supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure)
2. [error in Location Request class in android with kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386449/error-in-location-request-class-in-android-with-kotlin)
3. [error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598848/error-supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure)
4. ["Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved.” in Task:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154428/supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-in-taskappbuildinfog?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I am facing same problem. This is an issue of Kotlin Compiler. The bug is still open you can check it out here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24813. Right now I have to delete build folder and rebuild project then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

**I have faced same problem and its resolve by adding**

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'